# HAVING MAX in SQL Server 2005

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2005

I am looking for an answer for the following question

I have a database containing 3 following tables:

```
TB-001_ISB
TB-002_ISDB
TI-003_ISBDB
```

The data under table TB-001_ISB are

```
ISB_No                  ISB_Ad
121XS9060301            ANKARA CANKAYA
122CV9061501            ANKARA YILDIZ
123BN9062081            ANKARA KIZILAY
124GH8709034            ANKARA MAMAK
```

The data under TB-002_ISDB are

```
ISDB_ID                ISDB_Sit
F-10-01-MM             Factory Production
F-20-01-MG             Factory Quality
F-30-01-FM             Site
```

The data under TI-003_ISBDB are

```
ISBDB_No              ISBDB_ISDB_ID         ISBDB_Pers          ISBDB_Date
121XS9060301          F-10-01-MM            1234                01.01.2010
121XS9060301          F-20-01-MG            1234                02.01.2010
121XS9060301          F-30-01-FM            4321                03.01.2010
121XS9060301          F-20-01-MG            6785                04.01.2010
122CV9061501          F-10-01-MM            1234                01.03.2010
122CV9061501          F-20-01-MG            1234                02.03.2010
123BN9062081          F-20-01-MG            4321                03.10.2010
123BN9062081          F-30-01-FM            6785                04.10.2010
```

I need a query to get the following output:

```
ISBDB_No              ISB_Ad              ISDB_Sit         ISBDB_Pers          ISBDB_Date
121XS9060301          ANKARA CANKAYA      Factory Quality  6785                04.01.2010
122CV9061501          ANKARA YILDIZ       Factory Quality  1234                02.03.2010
123BN9062081          ANKARA KIZILAY      Site             6785                04.10.2010
```

So basically, I want the results to be sorted by ISBDB_Date and taking the max (ISBDB_Date)
In order to do so, I wrote the following query

```
SELECT  [ISB_No], [ISB_Ad], [ISDB_Sit], [ISBDB_Pers], 
(SELECT (Max([ISBDB_Date]) 
FROM [TI-003_ISBDB]
GROUP BY [ISBDB_No])

FROM  (([TB-001_ISB] INNER JOIN [TI-003_ISBDB] ON [ISB_No]=[ISBDB_No]) 
INNER JOIN   [TB-002_ISDB] ON [ISDB_ID]=[ISBDB_ISDB_ID])
```

However, there are problems with this query. Can anybody help me? All of the efforts are highly appreciated...

Comment: You should really specify what the problems are with the query before you can reasonably expect anyone to be able to help you...

Comment: What happens if you hav two `TI-003_ISBDB` records with the same `SBDB_Date`and `ISDB_ID `?

Comment: Actually, RedFilter you are right, but for ISBDB_Date data type, I use datetime and getdate() for the default value before entering values under the row.

Comment: That doesn't mean you can't get duplicates. It makes it difficult, but not impossible.

Comment: Then, how do I overcome this problem? Aaron, can you suggest any solution?

Comment: @SQL2005BGN - You need to choose a criteria for wich row to choose. In my answer, you are always choosing one row, but its arbitriary

Answer (score 1):

Try something like this:

```
WITH CTE AS
(
    SELECT *, ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY [ISBDB_No] ORDER BY [ISBDB_Date] DESC) Corr
    FROM [TI-003_ISBDB]
)
SELECT B.*, [ISB_Ad], [ISDB_Sit]
FROM [TB-001_ISB] A
INNER JOIN (SELECT * FROM CTE WHERE corr = 1) B
ON A.[ISB_No] = B.[ISBDB_No]
INNER JOIN [TB-002_ISDB] C
ON C.[ISDB_ID] = B.[ISBDB_ISDB_ID]
```

Comment: Why use a CTE when a correlated subquery does the same thing?

Comment: @Wil why use a correlated subquery when a CTE does the same thing?

Comment: @Aaron, touche...except a correlated subquery is simpler and more widely understood. Using a CTE for something like this - with a row_number() to boot, unnecessarily complicates the query. That's great, if someone's goal is to make their code so dense that there's no way they can ever be fired. Not so great if you have to be the one that comes along after they get fired and have to deal with it.

Comment: CTEs have been in pretty popular usage since SQL Server 2005. If you get fired because you used a CTE and the other guy couldn't understand it, I'd suggest they fired the wrong person. The ranking functions can come in very handy especially when self-joining, they're also very handy for recursion / hierarchy queries, and I like the fact that I can define the column names as part of the definition instead of mixing aliases in with expressions in the query.

Comment: @Wil - "if someone's goal is to make their code so dense that there's no way they can ever be fired" that's a huge exaggeration. I actually find CTEs simpler and more clear than a correlated subquery. I guess its all about the user.

Comment: Performance is another reason. On my box the the correlated subquery runs in .117 seconds. The CTE query runs in .999. Side by side with the execution plan the CTE has  64% of the query cost...almost twice that of the correlated subquery. So that's why :D

Comment: @Wil are you saying that a correlated subquery is always faster than a CTE?

Comment: @Lamak, see my comment above. The CTE does not perform as well as the correlated subquery.

Comment: @Aaron, I agree I and I was being hyperbolic. I love CTEs and use them where appropriate. But for something as simple as this...not so much. When all you have is a hammer and all that.

Comment: @Aaron, no in THIS instance it's faster. And that's what matters.

Comment: You're making a huge generalization based on two specific queries against one specifically indexed table with a certain data set. Do you even have the same indexes as the OP? What about actual data, skew, statistics, etc.? It's quite absurd to suggest that you should always use correlated subqueries because they're always faster than CTEs - even if you just mean *in this case* - again, do you really have what the OP has on your desktop?

Comment: I qualified that it was on my box, for this query, in this instance. I never said that they are always faster than CTEs. Anything that could be done to improve the performance of the CTE in terms of indexing, statistics, etc. would likely only improve the performance of the correlated subquery in this case. HOWEVER, I have identified problems with both queries to return the results requested - they need SELECT DISTINCT. Adding that alters the execution plans to be much closer to one another, so in the end it's going to be the poster's preference.

Comment: @Will - Why does this query need a `DISTINCT`?

Comment: @Lamak, only in the case of duplicate ISBDB_Date, which according to the poster should not happen. Also, for some reason I haven't determined DISTINCT makes the execution plan of both versions match one another more closely.

Comment: @Will - On my query, even if there is a duplicate Date, it chooses only one row (for the moment, its arbitriary), so there is no need for a `DISTINCT`, it is unique for date, that was the whole point of doing a `ROW_NUMBER`

Comment: @Lamak, it probably doesn't match the poster's data but if I run the exact same sample data into test tables multiples times and run the CTE, it returns back more than three rows (to be fair, my query does as well). It also kills the performance of both. Adding DISTINCT restores the performance and brings back only three rows. The thing is that we know that the data in TI-003_ISBDB repeats, so in the instance of duplicate rows (including ISBDB_Date), DISTINCT would be necessary.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT
    ISB_No
    ,ISB_Ad
    ,ISDB_Sit
    ,ISBDB_Pers
    ,ISBDB_Date
FROM  [TB-001_ISB] AS isb
INNER JOIN [TI-003_ISBDB] AS isdbd ON isb.ISB_No=isdbd.ISBDB_No 
INNER JOIN   [TB-002_ISDB] AS isdb ON isdb.ISDB_ID=isdbd.ISBDB_ISDB_ID
WHERE isdbd.ISBDB_Date = (select MAX(isdbd1.ISBDB_Date) FROM [TI-003_ISBDB] AS isdbd1
    WHERE isdbd.ISBDB_No = isdbd1.ISBDB_No)
ORDER BY isdbd.ISBDB_Date DESC
```

Comment: Will, many thanks for your suggestion but I do not have SQL server 2005 with me right now. So to try your query given above, I modified it to be able to run under Access 2007. However, the query asked me to enter ISB_No and ISBDB_Date. Does this problem result from the modification done by me, or will I face with the same problem under SQL 2005?

Comment: You will not have that problem under SQL Server 2005 (or 2000 or 2008). I do not know why Access would prompt you for those values, although I do believe you would have had to rearrange the JOINS to work with Access syntax and may have introduced an issue. If the query was for Access, you should tag the question as such.

Comment: No, the query was not for Access. Tomorrow, I will try your query and give information about the results.